# sh can't run executable

Tags: linux, docker, sh, alpine-linux

I tried to run a executable inside a docker container of alpine:

```sh
/usr/src/server # ls -l
total 57472
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           166 Dec 29 12:22 Dockerfile
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      58844530 Dec 29 12:35 server
/usr/src/server # ./server
/bin/sh: ./server: not found
```

It gives me the `file not found` error when trying to run the container, what am I missing?

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.12.3

# Create server directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/server

# Bundle server Source
COPY . .

# Expose Port and Start Server
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "./server" ]
```

The build Dockerfile (uses buildkit)

```
FROM node:14 AS build-stage

# Create server directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/server 

# Install Nexe
RUN npm i nexe@3.3.7 -g

# Install Server Dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle server Source
COPY . .

# Build
RUN nexe app.js -r config/db.js -r config/email.js -r config/passport.js -r config/config.env \
                -r middleware/auth.js \
                -r models/Option.js -r models/Token.js -r models/User.js -r models/Votacao.js -r models/Voto.js \
                -r routes/auth.js -r routes/votacao.js \
                -t linux-x64-12.14.1 \
                -o server

# Copy to Build
FROM scratch AS export-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /usr/src/server/server /server
```

The nexe stage is a mess, I'm still porting to webpack...

Comment: Where did you get `server` from? Remember that alpine doesn't use Glibc and there doesn't come with GNU dynamic loader.

Comment: Nexe generated it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nexe

Comment: Please share your Dockerfile contents for this image

Comment: You'll get that error if your image is missing shared libraries for the binary you built.  You might run `ldd server`, and see what that comes back with.  Also note that Alpine has a different version of some of the core libraries that can result in compatibility issues; looking at the Nexe documentation it looks like there is an Alpine variant of its base tooling, or you can build a Debian- or Ubuntu-based final image instead.

Comment: It solved, ldd gived me some problems, and debian run out of the box, please make an answer instead of a comment, to mark as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, ldd was giving me some errors:

Error loading shared library libstdc++.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by server)

Error loading shared library libgcc_s.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by server)

Using debian solved them.